# Why is using the framework's features considered wrong

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, frameworks

I joined a company as a junior developer and I get assigned to do maintenance and fixes to various applications.

In every project that I had to work in a team I always heard complains about my code being too "framework coupled" and that I should write the code using plain Java rather than using the Spring Framework's features (heck, I even got yelled at for using @Autowired rather than Constructor Injection)

I am really frustrated by this thing and I want to know if I am in the wrong. Aren't the framework's features the main reason a programmer is going to use that framework?

Comment: I recommend reading Uncle Bob's book "The Clean Code". --- No matter how severe the mistake, we should not yell at each other. I would suggest to look for an open dialogue. It is never a bad thing to a) admit that we do not understand something and b) ask for an explanation when we do not understand something.

Comment: and reading his "Clean Coder" after it :) Seriously, reading these two books is enlightening :)

Comment: @late1 Well... stand your ground. State clearly that you are hired as a junior developer. Policy at our company (and I think in most others) is that juniors need support and guidance. But be prepared to be laid off in case your employer is not willing to invest the necessary time. But then again... Is this really an emplyoer you want to continue working for? Those are question that only you can answer (and please do not answer here - answer them to yourself and act accordingly).

Comment: @Turing85 guess I'll have to read that book for now  and then do some changes :)

Comment: I guess you annotated private fields with `@Autowired`. The obvious reason that one should not do this is, that the class is now not testable without using odd hacks. The consumer of the class can't see that this class depends on other things etc. Oliver Drotbohm (the author of Spring Data) wrote a long time ago about the issues related to field injection http://odrotbohm.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/

Comment: @Andreas I didn't do that, however I encountered private Autowired classes the hard way, the IDE checked some classes as not used so I removed them (on my testing machine, not in production) and I was surprised to see that they were used somewhere, but they were private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the reasoning behind that way of thinking is that it would be easier to one fine day swap the Framework you use today to some other with the minimum required effort. You might argue that this isn't something very common or that you do very often, but still, even if the reason does not convince you it is generally a good practice to try to decouple your code as much as possible from the underlying Framework for multiple reasons (in addition to the one just mentioned you also have unit testing made easier).

In regards to the `@Autowired` topic, constructor injection is usually preferred for two main reasons:

1. You clearly define the dependencies for your class to work properly;
2. It is easier to unit test it because mocking its dependencies is way easier if you can "inject" them via the constructor.

Comment: If using the Constructor Injection makes such a difference, then I will use it and make everyone happy. Thank you for your answer and for the additional information regarding the Constructor Injection's benefits.

Comment: You are welcome. Since it seems that in your work environment supporting and guidance is not really a thing you will have to do it on your own, unfortunately. Try the books mentioned in previous comments and for Spring topics give https://www.manning.com/books/spring-in-action-sixth-edition a try ;) Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please do not get confused between two different concepts: "conding standards for particular project" and "best practices" - if you are a junior developer you just need to accept conding standards, if you are a team lead you should carefully evaluate whether the "best practices" are actually best. Spring Framework is not only DI-framework but it also provides a lot of other useful capabilities (externalized configs, post-processors, AOP, transaction management, converters, etc - a lot of them), if your team decided to not get coupled with Spring Framework it means they are missing a lot of features (or need to implement those features from scratch) for the sake of hypothetical possibility to switch DI-framework in the future.

As regards to the evilness of "field injection", the problem is evangelists of "constructor injection" completely leave out the fact that there are a lot of cases where it does not work at all, for example consider the following code:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class A {
  private final B b;
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class B {
  private final A a;
}
```

DI-framework will fail to bootstrap those beans due to circular dependencies, and you have the following options to make it work:

- do not use constructor injection
- put "somewhere" @Lazy annotation (or create your own proxy in order to stay clear of Spring). Where to put it? Actually in both classes, because the behaviour depends on the root of dependency resolution: if we start with `A` then `B` needs to be @Lazy and vice versa. But the problem is this workaround just moves the issue from bootstrap phase to runtime
- accept that you code smells and refactor it, but always keep in mind that bootstrap phase may fail any time, i.e. do the job that DI-framework is supposed to do